# OpenCart: Get product's url from cart

Tags: php, opencart

Is there a way to get product's url from cart?

In `checkout/cart.tpl` array `$products` contains information about all products in cart.
So I've tried to get first product's URL like this

```
<?php echo $products[0]->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_id); ?>
```

But it didn't work.
I hope you know solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product[0]['product_id']);
```

Comment: Ah, I thought you were looking to do this in the controller itself

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got this.

Just like I said, $products array, contains contains information(model, price, etc) about every product in cart.
Luckily, every product in $products array also contains url of itself(product). Property that contains url called 'href'
So, if you want to get product's url, you can get it this way

```
<?php echo $products[0]['href']; ?>
```

My english isn't perfect, but I hope you understand me.